# C++ add objects to string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I am trying to convert several values into one string, which is to be used as a filename, however after trying several different methods, I'm a bit stumped.

```
  string reportfile = myarray[0][2] + myarray[0][3] + "report.txt";
  cout << reportfile << endl;
  ofstream outfile(reportfile);
```

I've tried `to_string` and `.str()`, and I tried to add each of them onto the string separately, still converting the methods mentioned before, but I either did all of it incorrectly, or they it didn't work.
The arrays would contain year and day, I need the reportfile value to be, for example:

```
201312report.txt
```

So, how would I go about to converting the two int array items and the text into a single string.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what `myarray` is?

Comment: Sorry, thought the description was enough, myarray is all integers, containing year and month values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <sstream> // ^ top of the file

std::ostringstream reportfile;
reportfile << myarray[0][2] << myarray[0][3] << "report.txt";
std::string reportfile_str = reportfile.str();
std::cout << reportfile_str << std::endl;
std::ofstream outfile(reportfile_str.c_str()); // in c++11, ommit the ".c_str()"
```

This assumes there is an output operation from whatever type is stored in myarray (I assumed it's an integer type).

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 you can use [`std::to_string()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) for int-to-string conversions:

```
string reportfile = to_string(myarray[0][2]) + to_string(myarray[0][3]) + "report.txt";
```